# How can I get sharejs running with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm having trouble with nodejs and sharejs. I am trying to use sharejs and have installed via npm.  I can't seem to get it to load however. In my code all I have is the following:

```
var client = require('share').client;
```

when i call `node myfile.js`

I get the following error.

```
the variable "exports" can't be assigned with ?= because it has not been defined
```

I am a bit of a nodejs beginner and appreciate any help or pointers.

Thank you

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue on latest version (share@0.5.0-pre)

Comment: Are any tutorials for sharejs available anywhere? I haven't found any so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or make small fixes described [here](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/ShareJS/commit/d28778e1cac8895b97c9cb12ea06d7ea2bd6ee01)

Comment: The link in this answer is broken now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try installing an older version:

```
npm install share@v0.4.1
```